# perl multiline regex to separate comments within paragraphs

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, string-substitution

The script below works, but it requires a kludge. By "kludge" I mean a line of code which makes the script do what I want --- but I do not understand why the line is necessary. Evidently, I do not understand exactly what the multiline regex substitution, ending `/mg`, is doing.

Is there not a more elegant way to accomplish the task?

The script reads through a file by paragraphs. It partitions each paragraph into two subsets: `$text` and `$cmnt`. The `$text` includes the left part of every line, i.e., from the first column up to the first `%`, if it exists, or to end of the line if it doesn't. The `$cmnt` includes the rest.

Motivation: The files to be read are LaTeX markup, where `%` announces the beginning of a comment. We could change the value of `$breaker` to equal `#` if we were reading through a perl script. After separating `$text` from `$cmnt`, one could perform a match across lines such as

```
print "match" if ($text =~ /WOLF\s*DOG/s);
```

Please see the line labeled "kludge."
Without that line, something funny happens after the last `%` in a record. If there are lines of `$text`
(material not commented out by `%`) after the last commented line of the record, those lines are included both at the end of `$cmnt` and in `$text`.

In the example below, this means that without the kludge, in record 2, "cat lion" is included both in the `$text`, where it belongs, and also in `$cmnt`.

(The kludge causes an unnecessary `%` to appear at the end of every non-void `$cmnt`. This is because the kludge-pasted-on `%` announces a final, fictitious empty comment line.)

According to https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers, the `/m` regex modifier means

> Treat the string being matched against as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start of the string's first line and the end of its last line to matching the start and end of each line within the string.

Therefore, I would expect the 2nd match in

`s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$2/mg`

to start with the first `%`, to extend as far of end-of-line, and stop there. So even without the kludge, it should not include the "cat lion" in record 2? But obviously it does, so I am misreading, or missing, some part of the documentation. I suspect it has to do with the `/g` regex modifier?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $count_record = 0;
my $breaker = '%';
$/ = ''; # one paragraph at a time
while(<>)
{
    $count_record++; 
    my $text = $_; 
    my $cmnt;
    s/[\n]*\z/$breaker/; # kludge
    s/[\n]*\z/\n/; # guarantee each record ends with exactly one newline==LF==linefeed
    if ($text =~ s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$1/mg)  # non-greedy
    {
        $cmnt    = $_; 
        die "cmnt does not match" unless ($cmnt =~ s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$2/mg);  # non-greedy
    }
    else
    {
        $cmnt    = ''; 
    }
    print "\nRECORD $count_record:\n";
    print "******** text==";
    print "\n|";
    print $text;
    print "|\n";
    print "******** cmnt==|";
    print $cmnt;
    print "|\n";
}
```

Example file to run it on:

```
dog wolf % flea 
DOG WOLF % FLEA 
DOG WOLLLLLLF % FLLLLLLEA 


% what was that?
 cat lion


no comments in this line




%The last paragraph of this file is nothing but a single-line comment.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also delete the lines that does not contain a comment from `$cmnt`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count_record = 0;
my $breaker = '%';
$/ = ''; # one paragraph at a time
while(<>)
{
    $count_record++;
    my $text = $_;
    my $cmnt;
    s/[\n]*\z/\n/; # guarantee each record ends with exactly one newline==LF==linefeed
    if ($text =~ s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$1/mg)  # non-greedy
    {
        $cmnt    = $_;
        $cmnt =~ s/^[^$breaker]*?$//mg;
        die "cmnt does not match" unless ($cmnt =~ s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$2/mg);  # non-greedy
    }
    else
    {
        $cmnt    = '';
    }
    print "\nRECORD $count_record:\n";
    print "******** text==";
    print "\n|";
    print $text;
    print "|\n";
    print "******** cmnt==|";
    print $cmnt;
    print "|\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
RECORD 1:
******** text==
|dog wolf 
DOG WOLF 
DOG WOLLLLLLF 

|
******** cmnt==|% flea 
% FLEA 
% FLLLLLLEA 
|

RECORD 2:
******** text==
|
 cat lion

|
******** cmnt==|% what was that?

|

RECORD 3:
******** text==
|no comments in this line

|
******** cmnt==||

RECORD 4:
******** text==
||
******** cmnt==|%The last paragraph of this file is nothing but a single-line comment.
|
```

Comment: What is `/x` doing? https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%2fx-and-%2fxx says "Extend your pattern's legibility by permitting whitespace and comments," but this /x does more than that, correct?

Comment: I only used `/x` as a trick to avoid having `$.` interpreted as the special variable for the current line number.

Comment: Your substitution ignores or zeroes out everything from the match to the end of record, I think. How does this work on a multiline record without `/g`? I tried this code with `$str2="elephants, %really??\nbadgers  % more likely %Joe said no.\n% what was that?\ncat lion";`, that is, with 4  lines, the last one without any comment, and the outcome was only the 1st comment: `2: $2 = '%really??', $str = '%really??'`.

Comment: Yes you are right, so in the end you want `$cmnt` to contain all the comments (on all lines)? Is that correct? Se my updated answer

Comment: Yes. I want to iterate through a LaTeX file paragraph by paragraph and be able to match for a pattern, possibly across lines, either inside `$cmnt` or inside `$text`. It's entirely possible that `print "match" if ( $cmnt=~ /Bob\s*said\s*no/s );` could be a useful search (with "Bob said no" replaced by some other strings).

Comment: This solution is elegant and simple. Your single line deletes the irrelevant material, leaving only the comment. And I think that my `die "cmnt does not match"` line can be removed from the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

My main source of confusion was a failure to distinguish between

1. whether or not an entire record matches -- here, a record is potentially a **multi-line paragraph**, and
2. whether or not a line **inside** a record matches.

The following script incorporates insights from both answers that others offered, and includes extensive explanation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $count_record = 0;
my $breaker = '%';

$/ = ''; # one paragraph at a time
while(<DATA>)
{
    $count_record++; 
    my $text = $_; 
    my $cmnt;
    s/[\n]*\z/\n/; # guarantee each record ends with exactly one newline==LF==linefeed
    print "RECORD $count_record:";
    print "\n|"; print $_; print "|\n";
    # https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers
    # the following regex:
    # ^                     /m: ^==start of line, not of record
    # ([^$breaker]*)        zero or more characters that are not $breaker
    # ($breaker.*?)         non-greedy: the first instance of $breaker, followed by everything after $breaker
    # $                     /m: $==end   of line, not of record
    #                       /g: "globally match the pattern repeatedly in the string"
    if ($text =~ s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$1/mg)
    {
        $cmnt    = $_; 
        # In at least one line of this record, the pattern above has matched.
        # But this does not mean every line matches. There may be any number of
        # lines inside the record that do not match /$breaker/; for these lines,
        # in spite of /g, there will be no match, and thus the exclusion of $1 and printing only of $2,
        # in the substitution below, will not take place. Thus, those particular lines must be deleted from $cmnt. 
        # Thus:
        $cmnt =~ s/^[^$breaker]*?$/\n/mg; # remove entire line if it does not match /$breaker/
        # recall that /m guarantees that ^ and $ match the start and end of the line, not of the record.
        die "code error: cmnt does not match this record" unless ($cmnt =~ s/^([^$breaker]*)($breaker.*?)$/$2/mg);
        if ( $text =~ /\S/ )
        {
            print "|text|==\n|$text|\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "NO text found\n";
        }
        print "|cmnt|==\n|$cmnt|\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "NO comment found\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
one dogs% one comment %d**n lies %statistics
two %two comment
thuh-ree
fower
fi-yiv % (he means 5)
SIX 66 % ¿666==antichrist?
seven % the seventh seal, the seven days
ate
niner
ten

As Douglass said to Lincoln ... 

%Darryl Pinckney
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression modifier **mg** assumes that a string it applied to includes multiple lines (includes `\n` in the string). It instructs regular expression to look through all *lines* in the string.

Please study following code which should simplify solution to your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $breaker = '%';
my @records = do { local $/ = ''; <DATA> };

for( @records ) {
    my %hash = ( /(.*?)$breaker(.*)/mg );
    next unless %hash;
    say Dumper(\%hash);
}

__DATA__
dog wolf % flea 
DOG WOLF % FLEA 
DOG WOLLLLLLF % FLLLLLLEA 


% what was that?
 cat lion


no comments in this line




%The last paragraph of this file is nothing but a single-line comment.
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'DOG WOLF ' => ' FLEA ',
          'dog wolf ' => ' flea ',
          'DOG WOLLLLLLF ' => ' FLLLLLLEA '
        };

$VAR1 = {
          '' => ' what was that?'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          '' => 'The last paragraph of this file is nothing but a single-line comment.'
        };
```

Comment: According to perdoc perlre, regex modifier `/m` means that `$` matches the end of a line. And I think that `/mg` makes it happen repeatedly, for all end-of-lines in the record.