Why is this reluctant regex acting greedily? That is, in what circumstances does .*? match more than the minimum
my $file = '/a/b/c.xxx';
my $path = $file =~ s'/.*?$''r;
print "$path\n";
$path = $file =~ s'/[^/]*$''r;
print "$path\n";

The second substitution gives what I was expecting a/b but the first gives an empty string. Why is the .*? slurping up the whole string?
I understand .*? to be a reluctant match anything, matching the smallest possible amount. However in this case, instead of matching c.xxx it matched the whole string. In what circumstances will .*? match more than the smallest possible amount?

.*?$ matches all the line till its end since you added $. That is it.

.*? matches as much as it does because the whole pattern wouldn't match if .*? matched any less, as shown here.

Note that you want \z, not $.

Reluctant means "leftmost shortest match". Note "leftmost".

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048670/2173773

Thanks Håkon that was very helpful. The first thing it does is match the first / and then the reluctant match has to match everything else.

but be careful when using non-Perl regex. The principles may not apply. For example, in POSIX regex, principle 1 is not true. Instead: If the pattern permits a variable number of matching characters and thus there is more than one such sequence starting at that point, the longest such sequence is matched (see the example provided in the link)

.*? matches the shortest possible string at the position where it's matched, not the shortest possible string anywhere. And the pattern overall matches at the first position where it can succeed.
For a pattern of /.*?$ and a string of /a/b/c.xxx, the first position where the match can succeed is the beginning of the string, because the string begins with a slash, and therefore, "a slash, then zero or more characters, then end of string" does indeed match at position 0.
So, the / matches /, and the remainder of the string is a/b/c.xxx. .*? can match nothing successfully, so it does, but then $ doesn't match because it's not at the end of the string. So we backtrack, and try again with .*? matching a... but we're still not at the end of the string so $ fails. Try again with .*? matching a/... but we're still not at the end of the string.
Eventually, .*? matches a/b/c.xxx because everything shorter failed, and then $ succeeds because the match position is at the end of the string. The whole pattern now succeeded so the match is a success.
The difference between .*? and [^/]* here is that [^/]* cannot ever match a string containing a slash. Therefore, when the pattern tries to match at 0, its only options are to match nothing, or to match a, and neither one of those reaches the end of string, so the entire pattern can't match at that position. Therefore we have to try the entire pattern at a later position in the string. Eventually we try the possibility where the / matches at position 4, the [^/]* matches c.xxx, and the $ finds EOS, but there's no way to find success at any earlier position.

Your first mistake is not using the core modules that already do what you want. If you want the directory name, use File::Basename:
use File::Basename;
my $file = '/a/b/c.xxx';
my $dir = dirname $file;

As for the regex, a non-greedy quantifier at the end of the pattern is mostly pointless. There's nothing after it that need to match such that the non-greedy part actually needs to be non-greedy. The only thing it won't match is the newline because . doesn't match newlines. The $ anchor at the end is mostly pointless because the .*? is going to match until the end anyway. Once the substitution matches the first /, the rest of the string matches .*?.
Your second match, /[^/]*$ works because there's exactly one spot in the string where it can match a / followed by non-/ until the end of the string. It has nothing to do with the greediness.
Perl is always going to look for the leftmost, longest match. It's not going to try various things to get the least amount of text matched. In your first pattern, the leftmost match starts with the first character. In your second pattern, the leftmost pattern starts with the last / since the rest of the match cannot have / and must go to the end of the sting.
You can see this in action with Regexp::Debugger.
To read about the different options there, read Mastering Regular Expressions. It's not a simple story though.

Perhaps I should have said that I was aware of Basename, I gave that as a trivial example of a much more complicated situation to avoid complexity. I'll be careful in future about using non greedy quantifiers.

Paragraph 2 seems wrong. /.*?$ doesn't match the same as /.*?. Paragraph 4 seems oddly worded talking about "longest" in a discussion of reluctant operators.

I don't know what you see in the second para that says that. A . doesn't match a newline, so you don't really care if there is an optional newline at the end. For "longest", it's still the longest match it would make with what you specified and not the longest match with some other pattern you didn't specify.

.*? matches as much as it does because the whole pattern wouldn't match if .*? matched any less.

/ matches 1 char at pos 0.

.*? matches 0 chars at pos 1.

$ doesn't match at pos 1 ⇒ backtrack.


.*? matches 1 char at pos 1.

$ doesn't match at pos 2 ⇒ backtrack.


[...]
.*? matches 8 char at pos 1.

$ doesn't match at pos 9 ⇒ backtrack.


.*? matches 9 chars at pos 1.

$ matches 0 chars at pos 1





s{/[^/]*\z}{}r produces the result you want.
dirname from File::Basename works for even more inputs.
